# Show integer value labels in bar chart for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, charts, bar-chart, ios-charts

I need to create a bar graph to display some stats data, which I am able to display using iOS charts library.
    Only issue I am facing is that, the value labels above the bars are printed as double, I need them as integers. 
    I have tried searching it, but no positive results.
    Below is my code:

```
    barChartView = BarChartView()
    barChartView.frame = screen.bounds
    barChartView.delegate = self
    barChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    barChartView.layer.opacity = 0.0
    barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
    self.view.addSubview(barChartView)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should include a link to the charts library you are using.

Comment: What is `BarChartView`? Where is it declared? Please only show _relevant_ code. `backgroundColor`, `delegate`, `layer.opacity` etc are not relevant to the question.

Comment: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts appears to be the chart library.

Answer (score 5):

Make a custom formatter to change each value to Int.

```
class CustomIntFormatter: NSObject, IValueFormatter{
    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {
        let correctValue = Int(value)
        print("correctValue: \(correctValue)")
        return String(correctValue)
    }
}
```

Then set the formatter for your graph.

```
    let formatter: CustomIntFormatter = CustomIntFormatter()
    barChartView.data?.setValueFormatter(formatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define formatter and apply that formatter to dataset like below

```
     NSNumberFormatter *pFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
     pFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
     pFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 100;
     pFormatter.multiplier = @1;
     BarChartDataSet *set = nil;
     set = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithEntries:values label:@"Election Result"];
     [set setValueFormatter:[[ChartDefaultValueFormatter alloc]initWithFormatter:pFormatter]];
```